# Sprinting and weight lifting

Tags: weightlifting, strength-training, sprinting

> **TL:DR** I want to do one day weights, next day sprint, repeat. **Viable?**

Is lifting weights every second day, and sprinting every alternate second day a viable plan?

I am 6ft tall at 78kg(172lb), and do the lifts:

DL,Squats,BarBench,BarRows,BarbOverhead mainly. I am working on strength primarily with my weights. I believe squats and DL might have some trouble in regards to spriting viability.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

- I am willing to rest two days a week
- Currently I lift every second day(and am progressing slowly in strength gains)
- I will be eating at a caloric surplus
- I want to gain strength simultaneously

**Lifting stats:**

- Bench - 1RM 110kg
- Squat - I didn't realise I was above parallel for a very long time, so it was ~160kg, now below parallel it has went from 80kg starting to 100kg(only found out recently) for 3x5.
- Overhead - 1RM 70kg
- BarbRow - 1RM 70kg
- Deadlift - 1RM 130kgraw, 155kg straps

**Sprinting:**

Never done any sprinting and have no experience, haven't jogged in a long time either.

Comment: So right now you lift, and you want to sprint on your off days? Are you adding weight? Are you lifting 3 days a week, or 5, what? Do you plan on having any days of rest?

Comment: Take a look at what Jim Wendler does 5 days a week: http://www.jimwendler.com/2012/03/doing-more-with-less/, just as a point of reference for how much you can pack in a really intensive strength training program.

Comment: And Jim specifically talking about sprints and lifting: http://www.jimwendler.com/2011/12/hill-sprints/

Comment: Thank you @Eric I will read this now. I have done Wendler's 5/3/1 in the past, so I am a little excited before reading it.

Comment: @EricKaufman Glad someone mentioned Wendler.  Was thinking this looked similar.

Answer (score 2):

Sprinting sessions typically are once to twice a week.

When sprinting, you want to work with either low intensity (<75%), or high intensity (>95%).  Don't try and skirt the middle, as you won't ream any real benefit from it.

Low intensity will be good for development of improved sprinting form, active recovery, and improved endurance.

High intensity will allow for great adaptation when translating gains from resistance training and working said gains in concert with neuromuscular demands.

If you're going to sprint maximally, make sure you have **complete** recovery-at least 48 hours before you tackle sprinting again.  The way you plan on training lines up with that recommendation.

- Spend a little less than 60 minutes each session.
- 15 to 35 yards is a good jump off point.
- 4-8 Repetitions
- 1-2 sets

You should have a good amount of rest (about 5 minutes) between each sprint, and a little less than 10 minutes between each set.

All this is coming from EXOS, Dr Mann's body of work, and CharlieFrancis.com. I highly recommend you check them out, as sprinting mechanics are going to be a huge factor for injury reduction rates and improved times.

You can weight-lift heavily, but you may run into concerns with over-training.  The body can only take so much 95% and greater intensity.  Remember, rest is a weapon.  Use it.

Comment: It's very good to see the information for a proper sprinting workout regime. Is the <75% and >95% in reference to pulse? I will check out these websites soon, thank you.

Comment: I don't think heart rate would be a good indicator of your performance-time would be a better metric to follow, but the 75-95 is based on RPE, or your effort. (on a scale of 1-10, 10 is 100% of your effort).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a great idea as long as you can recover from day to day. Your fast twitch muscle fibers are getting a lot of work in. You really have monitor how you feel and whether or not you are getting stronger. If you are not either adding weight to the bar or reps to each set, then you are likely overtraining. I am of the opinion that as long as volume and intensity are added gradually, the body can adapt quite well. Take a look at construction workers, movers, manual labourers, they lift heavy shit everyday and are some of the strongest, fittest guys you will see. Their bodies have clearly adapted to the stresses placed upon them.

Hope that helps,

Mike

Comment: That is pretty much how I feel, thanks Mike.